# Use an object that only gets declared in the file including the original file

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, undeclared-identifier

Sorry for the confusing title but I could not think of a better way to word my question.

I have a class `Foo` which is declared in the file `Foo.cpp`.

`Foo.cpp` however, includes file `Bar.h` and class `Bar` tries to create a new instance of object `Foo`. Of course, I get an undefined identifier error. I need to include both headers in each file because I need to access some static members from each.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Example:
Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "Bar.h"

class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        _newNum = Bar::_num;
    }
private:
    int _newNum
};
```

Bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include "Foo.h"    

class Bar
{
public:
    static int _num;

private:
    Foo f; // Error occurs here, Foo is undefined according to Foo.h.
};
```

EDIT: AHHH sorry for a very poorly written question. I am feeling very tired. Fixed.

Comment: Missing semicolon (`;`) after class declaration? Also why are you including `Bar.h` with `Foo.h` and not vice versa??

Comment: Why does `Foo` include `Bar.h` if `Bar` is the one that needs to use `Foo`? This seems to be simply the wrong way round

Comment: Thank you for correcting my errors

Answer (score 1):

As far as your example goes, there is no reason why Foo.h needs to #include Bar.h.

To fix:

```
#include "Foo.h"
```

at the top of Bar.h, below the include guards.

Comment: My apologies for the poorly written question. I have updated it.